# MapReduce Hadoop StringTokenizer getting NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, stringtokenizer, bigdata

I am trying to use an output file from wordcount as an input file for a MapReduce that will show how many of each count there are (how many words appear once, twice, three times etc).

I want to use the count of each word as the key, and 1 as the value, skipping over the words themselves.

If the input file is something like this:

> 422
>   apple 3
>   fruit 2
>   gorilla 9
>   monkey 3
>   zebra 12

The output should be:

> 2 1
>   3 2
>   9 1
>   12 1

Using StringTokenizer to break up the file, the `nextToken()` in the map function below gives `NoSuchElementException`.

```
public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text count = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
        itr.nextToken(); // Skip over first line, which has just one element
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            itr.nextToken(); // Skip over word
            count.set(itr.nextToken()); // save count as key
            context.write(count, one);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why or how to fix it?

Comment: if your input pattern is always like **apple 3**, why don't you use `String#split` method to get `String[] elems` with two elements, and then use `elems[1]` as the count?

Comment: joanne see if my answer solved your problem. If so, you can mark it as accepted, otherwise, please let us know if the problem still exists or if you got a new error by following our advise.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow joanne and to MapReduce programming!

I guess that the reason is that you always skip the first token and ask for the next two. You do that for *every* line.

Keep in mind that the map runs in parallel for different parts of your input and not sequentially, starting from line 1 and then going to line 2. Each time, the StringTokenizer is called for one line only, not for the whole input.
Having said that, the solution to your problem is the following:

```
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString()); // each time the value is a different line
    if (itr.countTokens() == 2) { //this skips the first line and other lines that possible contain one word
        itr.nextToken(); // Skip over word
        count.set(itr.nextToken()); // save count as key
        context.write(count, one);
    }
}
```

**PS1:** You could also use the [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method, but that's up to you.

**PS2:** You might also consider writing the key as `IntWritable`, or `VIntWritable`, based on your data and requirements (slower to parse a String as int, but faster to transmit to network and lower memory consumption).